# How do I turn off the "This device can Run Faster" pop-up in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, popups

Running Windows 7 Ultimate on my machine and I use a KVM switch/hub. The switch/hub runs at USB1.1 max but works fine.
Trouble is I keep getting this notification bubble pop-up up every damn time I start the machine or switch to it via the KVM. The 2nd PC on the KVM runs XP and I have turned off the notification on that one - but can't do it on Windows 7

I click the pop-up and it gives me the dialog box with the option of a tick box saying "notify me if my device can run faster".

I have unchecked this box many times but the setting never seems to 'stick' and the next time I get the pop-up again.  Might be a silly Windows 7 admin privileges thing or something?

I know it is probably possible to turn off ALL pop-ups but I would prefer not to do that.
Anyone know how to make this setting stick?
Cheers

PS- I had screenshots of the popup and dialogs but I can't post yet cause I am new :(

Comment: See my answer below on the Device Manager box "Tell me if my device can perform faster"

Answer (score 5):

Windows 7 has the **Tell me if my device can perform faster** checkbox, which is probably better than disabling USB errors.

[image: Windows 7 USB]

Comment: See my answer, the problem that the asker ran into is handled in the Device Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Try going into Device Manager (devmgmt.msc) and open the properties for the USB Controller. On the Advanced tab, check off the **Don't tell me about USB errors** checkbox.

[image]

Comment: In Windows 7 it's actually better to use the newly added check box "Tell me if my device can perform faster" than using your recommendation.

Comment: @Molly7244: actually I disbled those checkboxes, but the error messages are still popping up. I did it for every USB-entry listetet in device manager providing the checkbox option.. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a handling for Win 7 that fully handles the problem:

1. Open the Device Manager (open Command Prompt and run devmgmt.msc)
2. Select the **Universal Serial Bus Controllers** node
3. Find the **USB Host Controller** (it may be called differently based on the hardware) and open the **Properties** box (with right-click)
4. The USB Host Controller that you need will have an **Advanced** tab, open it and uncheck the box `Tell me if my device can perform faster`

This will disable the warning for good.